# Does this truely generate a random foating point number? (Python)

Tags: python, random

For an introduction to Python course, I'm looking at generating a random floating point number in Python, and I have seen a standard recommended code of

```
import random

lower = 5
upper = 10
range_width = upper - lower
x = random.random() * range_width + lower
```

for a random floating point from 5 up to but not including 10.

It seems to me that the same effect could be achieved by:

```
import random

x = random.randrange(5, 10) + random.random()
```

Since that would give an integer of 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9, and then tack on a decimal to it.

The question I have is would this second code still give a fully even probability distribution, or would it not keep the full randomness of the first version?

Comment: [truly random != pseudorandom](https://superuser.com/questions/712551/how-are-pseudorandom-and-truly-random-numbers-different-and-why-does-it-matter). I think you're wondering if it still produces a uniform distribution, as @Vallentin answered.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I should have avoided using "truly random" in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) then yes `random()` is indeed a uniform distribution.

> `random()`, which generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0). Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator.

So both code examples should be fine. To shorten your code, you can equally do:

```
random.uniform(5, 10)
```

Note that `uniform(a, b)` is simply `a + (b - a) * random()` so the same as your first example.

The second example depends on the version of Python you're using.
Prior to 3.2 `randrange()` could produce a slightly uneven distributions.

Comment: Thanks! That should be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference. Your second method is theoretically superior, although in practice it only matters for large ranges. Indeed, both methods will give you a uniform distribution. But only the second method can return all values in the range that are representable as a floating point number.

Since your range is so small, there is no appreciable difference. But still there *is* a difference, which you can see by considering a larger range. If you take a random real number between 0 and 1, you get a floating-point representation with a given number of bits. Now suppose your range is, say, in the order of `2**32`. By multiplying the original random number by this range, you lose 32 bits of precision in the result. Put differently, there will be gaps between the values that this method can return. The gaps are still there when you multiply by 4: You have lost the two least significant bits of the original random number.

Comment: *But*, by generating two random numbers instead of one, the period of the PRNG is cut in half.  Though, this is not a practical concern for most applications.

Comment: Ah, but when you multiply a floating point number by a power of 2, you don't lose significant bits -- only the exponent is changed.

Comment: The period is certainly not a concern! The second method is less efficient, though, which may matter if a whole lot of numbers are needed quickly.

Comment: @Cameron, that's true. But the multiplications are not always exactly by a power of 2, and there's still only so many distinct numbers generated in the first step. (I might be exaggerating the _amount_ of information loss, though; still thinking about it.)

Comment: Thanks guys. This is a lot of good info on the trade offs as they would apply to a more demanding program.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods *can* give different results, but you'll only notice the difference in fairly extreme situations (with very wide ranges). For instance, If you generate random numbers between `0` and `2/sys.float_info.epsilon` (`9007199254740992.0`, or a little more than 9 quintillion), you'll notice that the version using multiplication will never give you any floats with fractional values. If you increase the maximum bound to `4/sys.float_info.epsilon`, you won't get any odd integers, only even ones. That's because the 64-bit floating point type Python uses doesn't have enough precision to represent all integers at the upper end of that range, and it's trying to maintain a uniform distribution (so it omits small odd integers and fractional values even though those can be represented in parts of the range).

The second version of the calculation will give extra precision to the smaller random numbers generated. For instance, if you're generating numbers between `0` and `2/sys.float_info.epsilon` and the `randrange` call returned `0`, you can use the full precision of the `random` call to add a fractional part to the number. On the other hand if the `randrange` returned the largest number in the range (`2/sys.float_info.epsilon - 1`), very little of the precision of the fraction would be used (the number will round to the nearest integer without any fractional part remaining).

Adding a fractional value also can't help you deal with ranges that are too large for every integer to be represented. If `randrange` returns only even numbers, adding a fraction usually won't make odd numbers appear (it can in some parts of the range, but not for others, and the distribution may be very uneven). Even for ranges where all integers can be represented, the odds of a specific floating point number appearing will not be entirely uniform, since the smaller numbers can be more precisely represented. Large but imprecise numbers will be more common than smaller but more precisely represented ones.